# How do I checkout a single file (not folder) from the SVN repository?

Tags: c#

Currently I am working on a C#.net project (visual studio 2005). I could checkout a project from the SVN repository, make changes to a file and commit.

But, how can I specify the checkout depth (sparse checkout) and checkout a single file by using sharpSVN DLL ? Please help.

Comment: Checkout this post. [Checkout one file from subversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122107/checkout-one-file-from-subversion/122291#122291)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checkout one file from Subversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122107/checkout-one-file-from-subversion)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that post; this post specifically asks how to use SharpSVN to checkout a single file, the other does not mention SharpSVN or C# for that matter.

Answer (score 4):

Subversion clients do not, so far as I know, generally support single-file checkouts. You can certainly *get* a single file (with nothing more than a simple HTTP GET request to the URL), but checking back in changes will be more difficult.

The reason for this is that Subversion wants to create its metadata directories (`.svn`) to track properties, URLs, the old version of the file, etc. That's hard to do in a single file.

Answer (score 0):

Like @derobert said, you cannot check out a single file. The best you can do is a non-recursive checkout of that file's directory.