# Checkout just one file from SVN using Team City

Tags: svn, continuous-integration, teamcity

Is this possible? Right now I'm using build artifact dependencies (I save the file from another build config in a .zip and add that artifact as a dependency in the build config where I need it). But I think this way would be more efficient.

I've seen that this can be done using command-line svn, but if possible, I'd like to do it using Team City's vcs root + checkout rules concepts.

Comment: Can you point me to where you have seen that this can be done from command line?

Comment: @manojlds: I put a link in my answer, last paragraph.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I checkout a single file (not folder) from the SVN repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708523/how-do-i-checkout-a-single-file-not-folder-from-the-svn-repository)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can't be done by Team City itself; its checkout rules only handle directories. In fact, [users have requested this feature](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-3460) and it's still pending. I have just voted for it. If you see this and need it, please vote as well.

Guess I'll do it from the command line. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122107/checkout-one-file-from-subversion) how.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working in TC using the "edit checkout rules".

So, let`s say you have a big root repo (BIG_REPO) where there is a multiple huge subfolders and one file that you want to check out (THE_FILE). This is a way :

1. Create and attach new SVN repo
2. As a REPO URL use this kind of URL : https://SvnRepoOfYourCompany/svnrep/BIG_REPO/THE_FILE
3. Go to the "Edit checkout rules" of the attached repo and use this rule :

   +:. => THE_FILE
4. Run the build and verify that the file has been indeed checked out
5. Party hard

Hope this helps. It`s quite bizzare that this is still not a feature in TC... maybe one day.