# How do I edit and commit a single file from a Subversion repository?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Using TortoiseSVN (a command line solution is OK too), without creating a folder on the repository side, what are the steps to checkout a single file, edit and check back in with comments?

Comment: I think you meant to say "without creating a folder on client side"

Comment: If thats the case, duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122107/checkout-one-file-from-subversion

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK you cannot get a copy of a single file from SVN, a working copy is always a directory. So you will need to check out a whole folder in order to edit the file in question and then commit.

This was the case some time back (less than 3 months) and I doubt it has changed since then.

Answer (score 3):

1. Right click in Windows Explorer where you want a working copy.
2. Choose *Check Out*. It might be in TortoiseSVN's menu.
3. Enter the URL and accept to get a working copy.
4. Make the change to the file.
5. Right click in the working copy. Choose commit.

**OR**

Refer to Stack Overflow question *[Checkout one file from Subversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122107)*.

Comment: AFAIK, you mus check out the entire folder (to get the .svn file), which means you CAN NOT just check out one file. If that is correct, then this is NOT a helpful answer. The URL is helpful, however. I'd remove the top portion of this answer and just keep the OR.

Answer (score 2):

To check out a single file, you'll still need to check out its parent directory. From the command line, to check out `https://svn.example.com/trunk/myfolder/index.html`:

```
svn co https://svn.example.com/trunk/myfolder/ --depth empty
svn up myfolder/index.html
```

Now, you can edit and commit this file as usual, without checking out anything else.

TortoiseSVN also includes "checkout depth" in its svn checkout menu option; however, I don't know of a way to make Tortoise do `svn up filename` on a file that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible with TortoiseSVN, but you must checkout the parent directory as well:

1. Create a working copy of the directory with no contents (use checkout depth "Only this item")
2. Click on the new working copy and right click to select the repository browser (*TortoiseSVN* -> *Repo-browser*)
3. Right click the file of choice in the repository browser and select "Update item to revision"

Answer (score 0):

You have a file **single.txt** you want to commit.

The right procedure is :

```
cd /path/destination_directory
svn up
svn commit single.txt -m "Insert here a commit message"
```

Hope this will help.