# SVN - How to upload a single file?

Tags: linux, svn, upload, import

How do I upload a single file from my local computer to a SVN repository?

I can import a directory, but I can't import a single file into existing directory.

I use SVN in linux (command line).

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:
I forgot to mention, I need to upload this file into a specific directory that has nothing to do with directory structure in my local computer (say I upload from Desktop).

So I want to upload a file from Desktop to https://.../somefolder

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768631/how-do-i-edit-and-commit-a-single-file-from-an-svn-repository

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, short answer is that it doesn't work like that :)
In SVN you work with a checked-out revision of your repository. In order to "upload a single file" you have to "add" the file with "svn add foo.txt" and then run "svn commit -m "Added file foo" foo.txt". But you can only do this to an existing repository. Therefore you must first checkout the revision (rev of trunk or a given branch) of the repository to add the file to. So the entire steps would be something like

> - svn co https://svn.internal.foo.com/svn/mycoolgame/branches/1.81
> - create your new file in the correct place in the folder structure checked out.
> - svn add *your new file*
> - svn ci -m "added file lalalalala" *you new file*

After this, you can delete your local copy again.

**8-year edit:** As mentioned [svn import](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.import.html) can also be used to accomplish this without having a local copy under version control. Do note though that this does so recursively and will add directories not present in the repository. This could be desired behavior or a source of potential errors depending on the situation.

Comment: Thank you. But you probably ment 'svn ci' (commit) in the last line?

Answer (score 28):

This can be done as the OP requires.

```
svn import -m "Adding a new file" file_to_upload.ext http://example.org/path/to/repo/file_to_upload.ext
```

This allows uploading a file directly into the repository without checking out to a local working directory.

Answer (score 1):

```
svn add filename
svn commit filename
```

Answer (score 1):

```
svn add /path/to/your/file.txt
svn ci /path/to/your/file.txt -m "This is where the message goes"
```

Or if you havn't added anything else just commit with

```
svn ci -m "Your message"
```