# How to get only updated files from svn?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-checkout

I need to checkout the files which all updated to particular revision from the SVN. It should not contain any other files. It should checkout the files were affected to a particular revision ID.  Also, I need to get the path as in the svn.

I am using Tortoise SVN under subversion control.

Any idea

Comment: Can be something like [this other post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971188/subversion-check-out-only-those-files-affected-during-a-specific-commit)?

Comment: thanks, I can get the affected files only. But the thing is, I need to get the path as in the svn. :( any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- TortoiseSVN Menu > Show Log
- Choose revision that has the modified files
- In files list, order by Action 'modified'
- Select all the modified files and Ctrl + C the selection
- Ctrl + V in your favorite text editor, such as Notepad

Answer (score 2):

**CLI-version**

`svn -q -v -r REV` or with --xml option additionally