# Download single file

Tags: svn, file, upload

How can I download single file from an SVN repository?

For example:

```
svn co http://server.com/svn/trunk/test.file test.file
svn: URL 'http://server.com/svn/trunk/test.file test.file' refers to a file, not a directory
```

But I can download directories in this way.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
svn export <URL> <PATH>
```

Path is optional

[svn export](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.ref.svn.c.export)

And for uploading a single file
[svn import](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.ref.svn.c.import)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can check out a single file.

If you just want the file and don't care about svn, you can use wget:

```
wget http://server.com/svn/trunk/test.file`
```

If you already checked out the `trunk` directory, and you are in your local copy, you can update a single file:

```
svn up test.file
```

Comment: We can do this using svn export <source_url> <destination_file>

Comment: You *can* check out a single file from Subversion. [It is done in two steps. First checkout an empty directory and then update a single file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122107/checkout-one-file-from-subversion/122291#122291).

Comment: Good to know, I'll keep it in mind in case svn ever somehow becomes relevant again ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
svn checkout <url_of_big_dir> <target> --depth empty
cd <target>
svn up <file_you_want>
```