# Checkout files from a different SVN directory to single target directory - SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

Is there a way to check out a single file from a different SVN directory to single target directory?

For example, in the SVN repository

```
svn://ddev/EDW/trunk/src/etlDataStream/ASGC
files: File1.dtsx
       File2.dtsx

svn://ddev/EDW/trunk/src/etlDataStream/HIRD
files: File5.dtsx
       File6.dtsx
```

I want this to be pushed to single directory of target systems as

```
c:\etlDataStream
files: File1.dtsx
       File2.dtsx
       File5.dtsx
       File6.dtsx
```

How can this be acheived?

Comment: Short answer - You cannot check out a single file in svn. Also, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122107/checkout-one-file-from-subversion for some possible workarounds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually do this with the latest version of Subversion. SVN supports `svn:external` for a single file from version 1.6. However, it has its own incompatibilities (it still has open bugs).

> http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.6.html#externals

Check *[Externals Definitions](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.externals.html)* for the implementation.

Comment: Yep, entirely possible on a file by file basis. Not entirely convinced it's a good idea tho.