# VisualSVN get specific file

Tags: visual-studio, svn, visualsvn

I'm new to using VisualSVN, and I wanted to know if you can get a specific file that has been added to source control in an upper level directory without have to update the entire directory (through windows explorer). For instance, if a co-worker adds a config file to the root directory of a solution, how do I get that specific file for my machine without getting latest/updating the entire solution folder?

Comment: What client are you using? VisualSVN is just a wrapper around SVN server, so client-side usage should be the same

Comment: Underneath, it's using TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 1):

You can do `svn export` using direct link to file with (e.g. `svn export http://svn.example.com/svn/repo1/config.xml`). This operation could be done using Tortoise SVN from Windows Explorer context menu. But keep in mind, that `svn export` is just a way to download file, wtihout any version control on it.

You also can do a sparse checkout (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/122291/1986575) answer).