# SVN commit without checkout or working copy

Tags: perl, svn, commit

I am working on a perl script which has to commit a new file every 10 minutes from my hard drive.

I was wondering if it is possible to perform a commit without having the working copy of the project whose commit I want to perform? Is it necessary to have a working copy of that project checked out on my hard drive before performing the commit?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it is a new file you can use the `svn import` command to directly import it into a particular folder in your repository

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.import.html

Comment: @vishalkbhatt: if this answers your question, you should accept it. (By clicking on the hook below the answer's vote counter)

Answer (score 11):

If this directory contains many other files with much content, a solution would be to do a [shallow checkout](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html).

```
svn checkout <url> <target> --depth empty
cd <target>
svn up <yourfile>
```

Edit your file...

```
svn commit <yourfile>
```

If you use an older version of subversion, you will probably find what you look for [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122107/checkout-one-file-from-subversion/122291#122291).

Comment: -1 But it **is** possible using `svn import`. See manojlds' answer.

Comment: OK, I though `svn import` worked only for new files. I should have checked that, though.

Answer (score 2):

Cause you are already in Perl you could use the Subversion Perl Bindings to solve your requirements. Take a look into [CPan](http://search.cpan.org/~mschwern/Alien-SVN-v1.6.12.1/src/subversion/subversion/bindings/swig/perl/native/Core.pm). It should be possible to do this for a single file. Take a look into the documentation about [SVN Modules](http://search.cpan.org/~mschwern/Alien-SVN-v1.6.12.1/) May be other examples would like [SVK](http://search.cpan.org/~clkao/SVK-v2.2.3/lib/SVK.pm) (take a look into the source code)

Comment: I got svn import working now..the only problem is the script should run in background and I dont know how to hide the command prompt window which is opened when the script is running the SVN Import command and performing commits.. any ideas guys how to hide is???

Comment: Then you are working on Windows. There are parameters for the start command ? Or are you doing this via cmd/bat files?

Comment: I got the problem solved already with following : `code use Win32::OLE; use Win32::GUI; $hw = Win32::GUI::GetPerlWindow(); Win32::GUI::Hide($hw);`

Answer (score 1):

SVN has a separate command `svnmucc` for committing to repositories without a checkout. See the docs:
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.working-without-a-wc.html

Answer (score 0):

You can commit using Subversion remote API. Here's the [example](http://vcs.atspace.co.uk/2012/07/20/subversion-remote-api-committing-without-working-copy/) for Java language, but the same API is used in other languages (C, Perl, ...). For [Perl bindings](http://search.cpan.org/~mschwern/Alien-SVN-v1.7.3.1/) SVNRepository class of the example corresponds to SVN::Ra.