# Checking out a single file with SVN?

Tags: eclipse, svn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Checkout one file from Subversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122107/checkout-one-file-from-subversion)

As far as I understand, [Subversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion) (SVN) only supports checking out a directory at the least. Is this correct?

If so, how does the History command in [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) allow you to look at an older revision of a single file?

Answer (score -1):

`svn log URL [PATH]` allow to work with files