# Check out a single file from a repository using SVNKit

Tags: file, svn, repository

Is it possible to check out a single file from an SVN repository using [SVNKit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SVNKit)?

I have code to checkout a complete directory. But I need only a specific file to be checked out.

Answer (score 0):

You can't check out a single file by any SVN client. You can get an **unversioned file** from a repository, using cat (redirected to file) or export.

Comment: You *can* check out a single file from Subversion. [It is done in two steps. First checkout an empty directory and then update a single file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122107/checkout-one-file-from-subversion/122291#122291).