# Jenkins plugin for checking out a single modified file from SVN

Tags: svn, jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins, hudson-plugins

I have a job in which the developer changes a file and checks back in in SVN. As soon as the developer checks in the file, [Jenkins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_%28software%29) has to trigger a build and copy that changed file (not entire directory) from SVN to a target server.

For example, a developer checked in a file in trunk in SVN. Trunk contains a huge number of files, but Jenkins needs to copy only the changed file from the SVN trunk folder to a target server.

How this can be achieved? Is there a plugin or functionality that helps support this feature?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot check out a single file from Subversion. The smallest unit you can check out is a directory.

If you already have a working copy, an `svn update` will pull the differences.

You can use `svn export` or `svn cat` to extract a single file from the repository, but it will not have a connection back to the repository when you're finished (unlike a working copy).

Comment: You can check out a single file from Subversion. [It is done in two steps. First checkout an empty directory and then update a single file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122107/checkout-one-file-from-subversion/122291#122291).

Comment: That's not checking out a *file*. That's checking out a sparse working copy and then selectively updating.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can setup another folder in SVN which will have *svn externals* link to that one file, and then check out that 1 folder.

As for deploying that to the server, that's up to you how you do that (plugins, scripts, whatever)