# Checkout a file in SVN

Tags: svn

I want checkout a **file** in SVN but return that message to me "svn: E200007: URL 'svn://mcdssrv/repos/currecnt/class/MBackingBean.java' refers to a file, not a directiry". so, how can i resolve that?
My command is:
**svn checkout svn://mcdssrv/repos/currecnt/class/MBackingBean.java d:\currecnt\class\MBackingBean.java**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checkout one file from Subversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122107/checkout-one-file-from-subversion)

Answer (score 3):

You can only checkout a directory, so:

```
svn checkout svn://mcdssrv/repos/currecnt/class/ d:\currecnt\class
```

If you want to avoid too many files/nested directories, you can use the `--depth files` or `--depth immediates` option.

If you just want the file, and not edit it / check it back in later, use `svn export`:

```
svn export svn://mcdssrv/repos/currecnt/class/MBackingBean.java d:\currecnt\class
```

[Edited] That being said, as someone ([@jyotsna-saroha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2264881/jyotsna-saroha)) commented below, TortoiseSVN manages to do it, and someone has proposed a [clever workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/122291/366749).

Basically, you have to do

```
svn --depth empty checkout svn://mcdssrv/repos/currecnt/class/ d:\currecnt\class
cd d:\currecnt\class\
svn update MBackingBean.java
```

Comment: Checking out a single file is possible with TortoviseSVN gui client.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. EXPORT command add file to my system but exclude that from SVN. i want checkout one file to  my system not a directory because some files in repository directory have problem. how can i do that?  :(

Comment: I edited the answer to do this with command line or TortoiseSVN client, please take a look above.

Comment: It works, but i have a new problem with that command. The problem is: when i execute that command one time that's work correctly but when i execute that command for second time for another file in that folder previous file deleted how can i fix that?

Comment: I suppose if you choose to checkout a single file, then the .svn information is stored for that one file, so the previous file can't be kept around, it won't be monitored by svn. I would recommend you try -"-depth files" to get all the files in the svn folder (non-recursive), and just update+commit the ones you want. In that case, the .svn info will know of ALL the files immediately in that folder.

Comment: As a side note, this process resulted in a .svn directory in the target directory. This would be '\current\class' using the example. This .svn directory was created even though a parent directory is already an SVN versioned directory.

Answer (score 0):

Latest version(s) of TortoiseSVN allow to checkout a single file. You should try upgrading your TortoiseSVN and then try the same steps again.

Comment: Yes TortoiseSVN can do this in every version but i want do this in svn(command prompt)