# IntelliJ - How to exclude a file when updating project?

Tags: svn, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I haven't yet found this functionality by looking in google or here, yet this seems to be a "huge" one:

In IntelliJ SVN is configured, I would like to update the project BUT I don't want to take everything... I can see this useful in a few cases:
1) I need to deploy a version by taking only a partial commit 
2) sometimes personal settings are committed (and you don't always have resources to change bad habits/settings)
3) just plain unwanted files

The obvious workaround to the problem I'm facing with (3) is to update, then revert back the files I didn't want but that seems very tedious. I come from `Eclipse` where in the update view I had the opportunity to select the files I wanted to update which was really useful.

I tried to exclude files from versioning in intelliJ, but this seems to only affect the commit procedure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Tell your developer friends *NOT* to commit personal settings.

In this situation I would usually: back up my own personal settings if needed, do a check out, delete the personal settings files and check in the "delete" to svn (thereby removing them).

Then, I would co-ordinate with other developers to add the appropriate svn:ignores in their local environments (e.g. *.iml, .idea, etc, etc).

Comment: yeah this would be ideal, but sometimes there is a legacy that you have to deal with... There are other scenarios where this is useful, I'll update the question with the issue I'm facing

Comment: true, but what's wrong with cleaning up "should not commit these type of files" files in the legacy? you have access to svn, after all.

Comment: The real use case I have is that I need to deploy a version for the client to test, but they only want a part of the fix - so I need to take 4 files out of the commit which is ~15 files big. Based on that they will decide of they want the complete fix or not. Weird, but still, I need to select files or use the workaround given in the question updated but that's tedious, especially since eclipse has it and intelliJ doesn't cease to amaze me so I guess they have thought about this.

Comment: Can you `svn export` the 4 files manually? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122107/checkout-one-file-from-subversion