# SVN import existing file

Tags: svn, command-line, import, subversion-edge

Is it possible to use svn import with a file that exists already?

Currently as workaround I do svn remove and than svn import. But the problem is that I have two revision numbers (two commits) and the entire diff is stored on svn server side instead of only the diff of the two files.

I don't want to make a checkout to have a solution for that.

Answer (score 5):

Use `svnmucc put SRC-FILE URL`.

E.g. run the following command:

```
svnmucc put C:\test\myfile.txt https://svn.example.com/repos/myfile.txt -m "My Commit Message"
```

Read about `svnmucc` tool in [SVNBook | svnmucc Reference—Subversion Multiple URL Command Client](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnmucc.re.html).

Comment: @DennyWeinberg `svnmucc` is not a third-party program. It's just another tool provided by Apache Subversion. You should already have it.

Comment: svn, version 1.8.16 (r1740329), svnmucc not found

Comment: For svn 1.7 it was part of the subversion-tools package

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help someone:
I cannot use `svnmucc` due to server infrastructure reasons.

Here is an alternative:
[Checkout one file from Subversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122107/checkout-one-file-from-subversion)
Solution: Create an empty checkout, update the single file, modify it and commit it.

```
svn checkout <url_of_big_dir> <target> --depth empty
cd <target>
svn up <file_you_want>
```

Source and "copyright": See link abowe.