# How to checkout just a part of the externals files in a svn repo?

Tags: svn

I have a svn repo and somewhere there are some externals to some folders in the same repo. when I checkout that folder containing the externals, svn is fetching also the externals, but I figured out that for the actual phase, only some of them are needed.

I know that doing a `svn co urlA myFolder --depth empty` and then a `svn up fileA fileB` just those files are in the `myFolder` (I've looked [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html) for understanding `--depth` option). But it seems that it does not work for the externals...

I've done this (supposing the urlA has 2 folders, one is fld and ext, that has the externals) :

```
$ svn co urlA fldA --depth empty
   U   fldA
  Checked out revision 115
$ svn up --set-depth empty fld ext
  Updating 'fld':
  A    fld
  Updated to revision 115.
  Updating 'ext':
  A    External
  Updated to revision 115.
  Summary of updates:
  Updated 'fld' to r115.
  Updated 'ext' to r115.
$ svn up --set-depth immediates fld ext
  Updating 'fld':
  Restored 'fld'
  Restored 'fld/header.h'
  Restored 'fld/source.cpp'
  At revision 115.
  Updating 'ext':
  Restored 'ext'
  At revision 115.
  Summary of updates:
    Updated 'fld' to r115.
    Updated 'ext' to r115.
```

even if I use the `propget` like [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.advanced.externals.html), the update is not checkouting the files and folders in the `ext`. More, I would like to just some files in the ext. Is it possible? Is there something I am missing out? Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I figured out a way to make it work. I made a bash script that is checkouting just the needed files :

```
#!/bin/bash

EXTERNALS=$(svn propget svn:externals .)

FILES=(header1.h source1.cpp header2.h source2.cpp header3.h header4.h source4.cpp)

IS_URL=true
for i in $EXTERNALS ; do
    echo "=========="
    if [ "$IS_URL" = true ] ; then
        URL=$i
        IS_URL=false
    else
        DIR=$i
        IS_URL=true
        svn co $URL $DIR --depth empty
        LIST=$(svn list $DIR)
        l2=" ${FILES[*]} "
        for item in ${LIST[@]}; do
            if [[ $l2 =~ " $item " ]] ; then
                svn up $DIR/$item
            fi
        done
        rm -rf $DIR/.svn
    fi
done

exit 0
```