# Using TortoiseSVN, is there any way to commit a file to a repo without checking out a working copy frst?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a new text file I want to commit to a certain folder in a repo. However the way I understand it, I have to first checkout (create a working copy) of that folder, and then only can I commit this new text file.

Is there any way I can bypass the step of checking out the folder, since the folder has other files in it which are pretty huge in file size.

Comment: Have you looked at answers to these questions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122107/checkout-one-file-from-subversion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Siddharth Kaul for pointing to another answer which helped!

For anyone stumbling on here and wants an answer, you can do

```
svn checkout [url] --depth empty
```

which will checkout the folder without any of the files